# HTTP Slow Post and IIS settings to prevent

Tags: security, iis, web, iis-8

So we got this report from a Security Company saying our MVC website running on IIS 8.0  was vulnerable to slow HTTP post DoS attack. The report stated we should

- Limit request attributes is through the `<RequestLimits>` element,
  specifically the maxAllowedContentLength, maxQueryString, and maxUrl
  attributes.
- Set `<headerLimits>` to configure the type and size of    header your
  web server will accept.
- Tune the connectionTimeout,
  headerWaitTimeout, and minBytesPerSecond attributes of the `<limits>`
  and `<WebLimits>` elements to minimize the impact of slow HTTP attacks.

The trouble is I'm having a hard time finding any recommendations on how these values should be set. Eg. the minBytesPerSecond is default 240, but what should it be to prevent SlowHTTPPost attacks?

Cheers
Jens

Comment: The difficulty for such settings are, you will have to observe the actual values of your web applications, and then set a moderate limit. There would be no guidance from others as their apps are different. You cannot remedy such security issues by setting a limit, but a suitable limit can lower the risks.

Comment: You're right, but how can I observe the actual values?

Comment: IIS log files contains the time taken field. Import them to database and start your data mining. There might be some automatic tools also.

Comment: Ok analyzing my IIS logs with Indishang gives me eg. one page with mean bytes sent 1567, and mean time taken 1656ms. Does this mean the page was sent with 1567/1,656 = 946 bytes per second?

Answer (score 8):

So, ended up following this guy's recommendations:

http://cagdasulucan.blogspot.se/2013/02/iis-recommendations-against-slow-http.html

Comment: Two years later and the settings don't seem to work at all. We're still getting the same reports on Slow Http Post vulnerability from our Security Vendor.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In our tests, we found out that Qualys is flagging the URL because **the server keeps the connection open for 500 seconds** while waiting for request to be completed.

The parameter that we edited for the connection to stay open during the slow response is `minBytesPerSecond`. the default value is 250. We set it to 400

[Prevent Slow HTTP POST vulnerability Denial of Service (DoS) attack](https://port135.com/2020/02/12/slow-http-post-vulnerability/)

Comment: Is this still valid? Did that change and many others and I'm getting that slow https vulnerability still. Already set weblimits and limits.