# Property handling timeout when downloading big files

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to download big files. To deal with slow connections, I have increased the Timeout property to 1 hour.

But, then, in case the connection is stalled (0 Kb/s for a reasonable time), I would like the connection to be forced to time out, because it's obviously an indication that something isn't going OK.

How do we deal with this situation?

Comment: 1 hour timeout doesn't really make sense, its better to catch timeout exception (let timeout to be just a few seconds) and then try to reconnect if necessary. obviously, you should continue the download instead of downloading from scratch (im not familiar with this API)

Answer (score 0):

We can call this as Slow HTTP Attacks (a kind of Denial of Service Attacks). In IIS 7 you can tune configurations below for protecting your services:

- Limit request attributes is through the  element, specifically the maxAllowedContentLength, maxQueryString, and maxUrl attributes.
- Set  to configure the type and size of header your web server will accept.
- Tune the connectionTimeout, headerWaitTimeout, and minBytesPerSecond attributes of the  and  elements to minimize the impact of slow HTTP attacks.

For further information Check [[1]](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks) [[2]](http://cagdasulucan.blogspot.com/2013/02/iis-recommendations-against-slow-http.html) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990459/http-slow-post-and-iis-settings-to-prevent)

Comment: Thanks for the anser, but I'm not on the server side, but on the client side. I would like to deal with stalled file transfers.